# Perform action after sign up in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

In my application I am using sending invitation by devise devise_invitable gem. After the user accepts invitation he is added as member in the system. Where I am facing error is that even if there is error and user clicks on sign up button the also he is added as member in the system. I want to first check that after signup user should be added as member in the system. I have added the following code in users/invitation_controller.rb file:

```
  def update
    user=User.find_by_invitation_token(params[:user][:invitation_token])
    @accepted_invitation = Invitation.find_by_invitation_token(params[:user][:invitation_token])
    session[:case_id] = @accepted_invitation.case_id
    @member = Member.create(:user_id => user.id, :case_id => @accepted_invitation.case_id, :user_type_id => @accepted_invitation.user_type_id)
    super
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a callback, though not the prettiest method.

```
before_save :add_as_member

def add_as_member
  if self.invitation_accepted_at_changed?
    #Member creation code
  end
end
```